# Apache's configuration: sharing same "Deny From" between multiple virtualhosts

Tags: httpd, access-control-list

I'd like to be able to share same "Deny From" from one VirtualHost to another in Apache's httpd configuration, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is better way, but if noone comes with anything better, just create a file with just the ACLs (ie. `somevhosts.acl`) and include it everywhere you need it using `Include somevhosts.acl` directive.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about that but wanted to see if there is something better then that...